# HowTo search for Jira tickets with open Crucible review

Tags: jira, atlassian-crucible

Is there a way to search (in the Jira Advanced Search, not in fisheye or crucible search) for Jira tickets for which:

- a Crucible review exists
- the review is not in state "closed"

Answer (score 0):

project = "xx" AND type = xx AND status = done AND (issue.property[development].prs > 0 OR issue.property[development].commits > 0) AND issue.property[development].openreviews > 0

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.